# How to change the color of points using shaders

Tags: opengl, colors, shader, glut

I have an application where I draw a bunch of points on a GLUT window.  I have a vertex shader and a frag shader, which I gave a color input.  My vertex shader looks like:

```
#version 120
attribute vec2 position;

varying vec4 vColor;

void main()
{
   vColor = gl_Color;
   gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

and my frag shader looks like:

```
#version 120

varying vec4 vColor;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

I'd like for the user to be able to change the color of the points based on a key press.  So, I have some key press handling function:

```
void handleKeyPress(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'c')
       //todo: change the point colors to green
}
```

How do I do that "todo"?

Answer (score 2):

With those shaders you can just issue a `glColor()` before you draw:

```
glColor3f( r, g, b );
// draw geometry
```

But fixed-function interop pre-defined variables (`gl_Color` in the vertex shader) are kinda pointless if you're already using generic vertex attributes for position.

In which case you can use [`glUniform()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glUniform.xml) instead:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// RAII vertex attribute wrapper
struct Attrib
{
    Attrib
        ( 
        const char* name, const GLint size, const GLsizei stride, const GLvoid* pointer, 
        const GLenum type = GL_FLOAT, const GLboolean normalized = GL_FALSE, const GLuint prog = GetProgram() 
        )
    {
        mLoc = glGetAttribLocation( prog, name );
        if( mLoc < 0 ) return;
        glVertexAttribPointer( mLoc, size, type, normalized, stride, pointer );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( mLoc );
    }

    ~Attrib()
    {
        if( mLoc < 0 ) return;
        glDisableVertexAttribArray( mLoc );
    }

    GLint mLoc;

private:
    static GLuint GetProgram()
    {
        GLint program = 0;
        glGetIntegerv( GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &program );
        return program;
    }
};

// GLSL shader program loader
struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char* vert = GLSL
(
    120,
    attribute vec2 position;
    void main()
    {
       gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }    
);

const char* frag = GLSL
(
    120,
    uniform vec3 uColor;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( uColor, 1.0 );
    }    
);

float r = 1, g = 0, b = 0;
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == 'c' )
    {
        r = 1 - r;
        g = 1 - g;
        b = 1 - b;
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // prepare to render
    static GLuint prog = Program::Load( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    glUniform3f( glGetUniformLocation( prog, "uColor" ), r, g, b );

    float verts[] = {
        -1 / 2.0, -1 / 2.0,
         1 / 2.0, -1 / 2.0,
         1 / 2.0,  1 / 2.0,
        -1 / 2.0,  1 / 2.0,
    };

    {
        Attrib a1( "position", 2, 0, verts );
        glDrawArrays( GL_QUADS, 0, 4 );
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int extra )
{
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();

    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a really useful attrib for OpenGL. Couldn't do the same with DX but for OpenGl dat's Niiice. :O

Comment: Thanks!  I have an extra-lazy one lying around somewhere that does away with the `prog` argument (by querying OpenGL for the current program ID) as well as default-argumenting some lesser-used things.  I'll try to dig it up and edit it in.

Comment: Don't go to all that trouble, if it's just for me. I'm actually working in DirectX these days (and getting my ass kicked by deferred rendering). I'm going to port everything to OpenGL soon though, so when that happens I'll be sure to totally slide on over towards this answer and grab this for when I need to work with attributes. :P

Answer (score 0):

there's an OpenGL function called [glVertexAttrib](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttrib.xml), allowing you to set a vertex attribute to a fixed value for a whole draw call instead of fetching per-vertex values out of a vertex buffer object. The advantage of using this over specifiying a uniform variable with the color is that you can then render both geometry with individual per-vertex colors AND geometry that has no such attribute with the same vertex/fragment shader pair.